# Italics display issue on Firefox and Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, firefox, text

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and use LivePatch. I don't restart my computer that often, but this week after I did, I noticed that all italics text is messed up and not rendering properly in Firefox. I don't know what this phenomenon is called, but here's a screenshot of what italicized text on this page look like. You'll notice code and bolding work but not the italicized code.[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn9aq.png)

Is there someplace to report this or a way I can fix this? I'll note this happens on all websites in Firefox, and even when I turn off all extensions. I'm running Firefox 77.0.1-1 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue. It gets fixed when I restart Firefox and it is not clear to me what is causing it.

You are running the snap package of Firefox, because `Firefox 77.0.1-1` is the version number of the snap package.

What happens, is that for some reason, Firefox from the snap package cannot find any suitable font to display italics for some specific font style. When no font is found for a specific style, the system shows those boxes and in them, puts the Unicode codepoint of the missing character. In your screenshot, [the `002A` is the `*` character](http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=U%2B002A).

If instead those boxes where empty, then that would mean that the encoding is bad, a different problem.

I suggest to restart Firefox (close all windows) and try again.

Then, run `snap info firefox` and check the *refresh-date*, to see whether it was just updated.

This issue qualifies as a bug report on https://forum.snapcraft.io

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Restarting did seem to fix this, but I'm not clear if it's temporary or if same issue will happen again later! I checked the refresh-date, which is 2 days ago, but I think that's when the problem may have begun, I'm not sure. I'll post a bug report where you suggested, thanks.